# modifying value of global variable within a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, variables, parameters, global-variables

I am using vue to try and set the values of checkboxes. Here is some code below:

```
let variable = false;

export default {
  name: "nyle-home",

  created() {
      this.notifstate = this.$route.params.data[0].state;
      variable = this.notifstate;
      console.log(variable); //outputs true
  },
  data() {
    return {
      weather: {
        state: variable,
        number: "",
      },
      submitted: false
    };
  },
};
```

I am trying to set state equal to the valuable of variable after created() executes which is true. However, the code is setting state equal to the initial value of variable which is false. How can I ensure that state takes on the value of variable after created()?

Answer (score 1):

Set your data directly in the 'created' hook:

```
  created() {
      this.notifstate = this.$route.params.data[0].state;
      variable = this.notifstate;
      console.log(variable); //outputs true
      this.weather.state = this.notifstate;
  },
```